# Calculating mean and estimating variance of ratios

Tags: variance, ratio

I am a biologist with very limited statistics/mathematics background who frequently encounters the same problem when trying to analyse a specific type of data, but would like to finally begin to understand how I approach this properly. I will try explain the basis of the experiment and then describe the output I'd like;

We're looking at survival of two different strains (S1 and S2) of the same bacterial species on a range of surfaces. Each strain is placed on a surface and at specific timepoints (say t-1hr) the amount of viable cells are determined - this sum is divided by the initial inoculum (t-0hr) to produce a ratio of viable cells. This is repeated in triplicate for each strain - so my first question is:

> a) what is the most accurate way to find the mean and estimate the error of the calculated ratios for each time point?

Let's say x = t-0hr and y = t-1hr

Replicate 1: x = 6x10^7 y = 4x10^6   ratio =  0.0667
Replicate 2: x = 3x10^7 y = 1x10^6   ratio =  0.0333
Replicate 3: x = 9x10^6 y = 9x10^4   ratio =  0.01

I want a mean of the ratios ± some estimate of the variance and I feel like simply adding those ratios together and dividing by 3 is incorrect.

Once I have a mean and error for S1 and S2 for each timepoint, I then want to examine whether these means are significantly different between strains, ideally at each timepoint - in essence, is one strain better are surviving on that surface after a given time. How would I then go about that?

I feel like this is extremely basic but I have spent a lot of time trying to find the correct answer in these and other forums and the answers are always far too in-depth for me to even slightly understand and require quite a substantial amount of prior knowledge regarding mathematics.

Many thanks in advance for your time!

Chris

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that each viable cell at time t-0hr will still be viable at time t-1hr with the same probability (independently of the other cells)?

Comment: Yes, that would certainly be a reasonable assumption for this experiment

Answer (score 0):

The ratio of interest to you is a ratio of two random variables. That is, a count of survivors divided by a count of original cases. This often occurs in biological measurements. These could be counts made in the field or in a petri dish or other places.

Both the components of a ratio appear to be random. (The denominators don't seem to be fixed by the design of the experiment.) Ratios of this sort are often highly variable. Most rates are close to zero, but some can have long tails to the right.

Ratios of this sort are often analyzed on a log scale. (Sometimes there is a biological basis for this.)

You can do this by computing the log of each ratio to start. Then calculate the average of these logs and finally the antilog of the average. Use this as an estimate of the rate.

A standard error and confidence interval can also be calculated on the log scale, eg, a 95% interval. The antilogs of these lower and upper values can be used as a confidence interval for the rate above, that is, the antilog of the average of the logs of the ratios.

Answer (score 0):

Working in the log scale as David Smith recommends is often reasonable in biology and biochemistry, if the observations all have positive values. With $\log(Y/X)=\log Y - \log X$, the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Weighted_sum_of_variables) means that the variance of the log of a ratio is simply:

$$ \text{Var} \left(\log \frac{Y}{X}\right)=\text{Var}(\log Y) + \text{Var}(\log X) - 2\text{Cov} (\log Y, \log X),$$

where $\text{Cov}$ is the covariance. The covariance between paired measurements in ratios like yours can give more precise estimates of effects than you might get with unpaired measurements.

One first caution: when you start with a log transform of your outcome observations, you are modeling the means of their logs, which isn't the same as the log of their means. A standard error in the log scale doesn't translate back to a single value in the original scale, although confidence intervals can have reasonable interpretations. That's all OK if you and your audience understand that's what you're doing.

A second caution: you almost certainly didn't count each of 60 million cells in an inoculate, or each of 4 million remaining in the plate after an hour. Those are presumably estimates based on a much smaller number of counts of some sample of the inoculate and of the plate. You usually want to work as closely as possible in the scales of the original observations, so that you can better estimate the errors inherent in the observations.

In particular, observations of counts typically have a Poisson distribution, with the variance equal to the mean. A count of $100$ thus has an inherent Poisson standard error of $\pm 10$, or 10% error. If your per-inoculate or per-plate observations are based on much larger counts (on the order of 1000 or so) then that won't be a big problem, but you should be aware of this in general.

A third caution: you should re-think how you handle the standard errors:

> Once I have a mean and error for S1 and S2 for each timepoint, I then want to examine whether these means are significantly different between strains, ideally at each timepoint - in essence, is one strain better are surviving on that surface after a given time. How would I then go about that?

For that you don't typically want to work with means and standard errors for each timepoint individually. There's a pretty large error in the estimate of the standard error from any small number of observations. You usually use your data more efficiently if you analyze your combined data in a single model to get a pooled estimate of the error.

With your paired observations of initial $x$ values and final $y$ values, you might set up a regression model that includes all of your data. There would be one data row per inoculate/plate pair, including the $x$ and $y$ values and annotations of the `strain` and the `surfaceType`.   The regression model could use $(\log y - \log x)$ as the outcome, with `strain`, `surfaceType`, and their interaction as predictors. That would allow for different sensitivities of the strains to the various surfaces. Tests of significance would be based on a pooled estimate of the error not accounted for by strain or plate type. Similar models can be extended to multiple time points.

Post-modeling tools like those in the R [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) can use the results of the regression model to evaluate the means and confidence intervals for any estimates of particular conditions, or differences between estimates. They can translate back out of the log scale if you wish, and properly take into account the [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) that are inherent in this type of study.